# Opera crash after Windows 10 update

Tags: crash, opera

Today after installing last Widows 10 update when I try to open the browser the message comes: "this page crashed". I disinstalled and reinstalled Opera last version a few times but the problem persists.

Comment: Can you be more specific than the “last Windows update”?  There are several “last Windows updates” that were released on Tuesday

Comment: Sometimes when something isolated like that happens, I run DISM and SFC.  Uninstall Opera.  Open an admin command prompt.  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth   then SFC /SCANNOW .  Now restart and install Opera again and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your prompt reply. The last Windows 10 update was installed the same day of my post.
First I moved all bookmarks to Yandex browser. Second I followed the instractions step by step from YouTube "How to uninstall Opera browser completely from windows PC", then, supposing that last Opera version could be incompatible with the last Windows 10 update, I installed a previous February 2021 Opera version. I retrieved the bookmarks from Yandex and I had to reinstall all previous extensions.
Now Opera works perfectly.

Best regards. Mario